# wget throwing errors on vulnerable machine

Tags: vpn

I’m trying to crack a Proving Grounds machine. I was making great progress, but once I got in, `wget` refused to work. On small files (i.e. one that contains a single string) it works fine, but for any exploit, scanner, etc. it hangs and throws a “Read error at byte 0/*filesize*” error at me.

There’s nothing wrong with my file, syntax, or permissions, I’ve been triple checking those for days. I’m connected to a vpn to access the machine, so I’m wondering if there’s something misconfigured there? I’m unsure how to double-check, though, and haven’t found anything like this online.

Also, I double-checked, and this is *not* how the machine is intended to work. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I'm confused: "but for any exploit, scanner, etc" - are you using `wget` for those things?

Comment: This is looking like a networking troubleshooting issue, not a security issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543048/wget-gets-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer-in-headers  You may want to try some of the suggested solutions/workarounds on this page.